# Unwanted Shadow below water in eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, shadows

I used pure toon water addon to make a river and put rock and fish below. However, I find there is unwanted small black spot (I believe it is shadow). Is it due to lighting issue, or others? Could somebody provide assistance on how to eliminate such small black shadow on the surface of rock and fish. Thank you.[image]

Comment: I believe you are correct about the shadow. I don't know how it works in the add-on, but  if the water has a material, you can change it there. In the the material properties panel, with your water material selected, scroll down until you see "blend mode" and "shadow mode". Set "shadow mode" to "none", and see if it makes the dots disappear

Comment: It works. Thanks a lot